# Serverless S3 bucket events enabling default encryption in template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, serverless-framework, serverless

According to https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/s3/
I can create an S3 bucket in the serverless template that triggers an event when a jpg file gets dropped into the uploads directory. Great!

```
functions:
  users:
    handler: users.handler
    events:
      - s3:
          bucket: photos
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          rules:
            - prefix: uploads/
            - suffix: .jpg
```

With another example for when you want add custom S3 bucket properties. Also great!

```
functions:
  resize:
    handler: resize.handler
    events:
      - s3: photos

resources:
  Resources:
    S3BucketPhotos:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: my-custom-bucket-name
    ResizeLambdaPermissionPhotosS3:
      Type: "AWS::Lambda::Permission"
      Properties:
        FunctionName:
          "Fn::GetAtt":
            - ResizeLambdaFunction
            - Arn
        Principal: "s3.amazonaws.com"
        Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction"
        SourceAccount:
          Ref: AWS::AccountId
        SourceArn: "arn:aws:s3:::my-custom-bucket-name"
```

If I want to add default encryption to that bucket, I need to create the bucket in the Resources section of the template, and reference it in the event handler, ok I can do that.

```
functions:
  resize:
    handler: resize.handler
    events:
      - s3: photos

resources:
  Resources:
    S3BucketPhotos:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: my-custom-bucket-name
        BucketEncryption:
          ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration:
            - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
                SSEAlgorithm: AES256
```

But now I'm stuck on how I specify the event and rules (prefix and file type) that I want to be triggering the handler. I can't add them to the resize handler block, and I'm having trouble scouring the documentation find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't add them in the resize handler block

I believe you can.  Declaring the bucket in the `resources` section doesn't remove your ability to specify rules in your handler's S3 event.

Full example used to test:

```
functions:
  resize:
    handler: handler.s3EventProcessor
    events:
      - s3: 
          bucket: photos
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          rules:
            - prefix: uploads/
            - suffix: .jpg          
resources:
  Resources:
    S3BucketPhotos:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: ${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}
        BucketEncryption:
          ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration:
            - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
                SSEAlgorithm: AES256        
    ResizeLambdaPermissionPhotosS3:
      Type: "AWS::Lambda::Permission"
      Properties:
        FunctionName:
          "Fn::GetAtt":
            - ResizeLambdaFunction
            - Arn
        Principal: "s3.amazonaws.com"
        Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction"
        SourceAccount:
          Ref: AWS::AccountId
        SourceArn: "arn:aws:s3:::${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}"
```